# Elastics search query to filter out result having value A in list but not B

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to form a query where, requirement is to filter only those data where country is india but not usa.

Sample data.

```
{
  "data": {
    "attributes": {
      "name": "test",
       "country": ["india","usa","japan"]
    }
  }
}
```

As , in the above example we have both india and usa, it should not filter the result.

whereas it should filter if the data is in the format mentioned below.

ex1:

```
{
  "data": {
    "attributes": {
      "name": "test",
       "country": ["india","japan"]
    }
  }
}
```

ex2:

```
{
  "data": {
    "attributes": {
      "name": "test",
       "country": ["india"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: have you had any success with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The question, looked a bit confusing. I am assuming, you don't want India and USA to come together. Based on the above assumption, the below query is shared.

```
"query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                    "term": {
                        "tags": {
                            "value": "india"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must_not": [{
                    "term": {
                        "tags": {
                            "value": "usa"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is "commodo" and "velit"? And where do you see a tags field in the shared sample documents?

Answer (score 0):

The query looks like this:

```
GET countries/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "data.attributes.country.keyword":{
              "value": "india"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "data.attributes.country":{
              "value": "usa"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.16786805,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "countries",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 0.16786805,
        "_source" : {
          "data" : {
            "attributes" : {
              "name" : "test",
              "country" : [
                "india"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "countries",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 0.13353139,
        "_source" : {
          "data" : {
            "attributes" : {
              "name" : "test",
              "country" : [
                "india",
                "japan"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

```
PUT countries  

PUT countries/_doc/1
{
  "data": {
    "attributes": {
      "name": "test",
      "country": [
        "india",
        "usa",
        "japan"
      ]
    }
  }
}

PUT countries/_doc/2
{
  "data": {
    "attributes": {
      "name": "test",
      "country": [
        "india",
        "japan"
      ]
    }
  }
}

PUT countries/_doc/3
{
  "data": {
    "attributes": {
      "name": "test",
      "country": [
        "india"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter` (or `must`) and `must_not` clauses in a `boolean` query. In case I understood your requirement correctly, you could use the following.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "filter": {
        "term" : { "data.attributes.country" : "india" }
      },
      "must_not" : {
        "term" : { "data.attributes.country" : "usa" }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

The documentation for both [`boolean`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) and [`term`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) are quite extensive and contain many example.